# Keeping my session after scripts ends

Tags: php, session, curl, authentication

I wonder if is possible to keep the login while the cookie exists so i just need to do the login once, even on with differents scripts. I'm doing the things like this:

```
$tempCookie = 'mycookiefile';

//Begins with the base URL to save cookies
$ch = curl_init($url);        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $tempCookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $tempCookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");        
curl_exec($ch);    

//Now i do the login
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
            array('username' => $usuario, 'password' => $password));
echo curl_exec($ch); //the login works
```

And now i do my stuff to get data from the url. 
Could I skip all the login process and do it only once? like when we close a browser's window and we come back and we are still logged.

Comment: [Check this](http://www.codesend.com/view/36e6397d47bedf0fe2b4cf7bd44b3aab/), may help you, didn't try it but curious and if it works then please post the solution as an answer.